# Error when trying to Pkg.add("Playground") in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to install `Playground` in Julia 1.7.2 in order to make a virtual environment. However, when I go about `julia> Pkg.add("Playground")` the following error appears:

```
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Playground (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

I am not sure what is happening and how to properly resolve this issue in the most convenient way. Could it be a version incompatibility issue?

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/rofinn/Playground.jl ? This appears to have last worked on Julia 0.6, which was a long time ago. I don't know quite what it used to do, but external "virtualenv"-like things are generally not needed, the built-in package manager handles all of this cleanly.

Comment: Yeah, Julia's inbuilt `Pkg` takes care of virtual environments cleanly. See also: https://github.com/rofinn/Playground.jl/issues/84#issuecomment-502472959 (`Pkg3` = current `Pkg`). Even the (uncommon) use case mentioned there, afaict, is taken care of by setting `DEPOT_PATH` (which, I should stress, isn't required for most people).